# Custom Attribute Display image errors in ArcGIS online popups

Tags: arcgis-online

I am trying to add images in the Custom Attribute Display of arcgis.com map editor as opposed to the conventional Pop-up Media area because I want to organize them in a custom way.

However no matter what I try, it always says 'The Value entered is not valid'.
I want the photo in the popup so I don't want to use the link option.

I have tried having "http://" in my field and not. When using related table fields, the add image box would append it, but doesn't seem to when using non-related table fields.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently the image needs to be contained in the media info. I would recommend checking to see if this is in the ArcGIS Ideas page on geonet and if not posting that there.